# Autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: reactjs, sass, netlify, autoprefixer

When I try to publsish the app via netlify I get the warning:

> (1:584) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

This is the project repo: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/OsmanAbdullayev/ecommerce-food-final-project)

*P.S. This project is written with React JS and Bootstrap was used.*

These are the package.json and Netlify Log:

```
{
    "name": "ecommerce-food-final-project",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "overrides": {
        "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
        "detect-browser-language": "^0.0.2",
        "emailjs": "^4.0.1",
        "firebase": "^9.17.1",
        "i18next": "^22.4.15",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.1",
        "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^5.1.0",
        "notiflix": "^3.2.6",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
        "react-confirm-alert": "^3.0.6",
        "react-country-region-selector": "^3.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-i18next": "^12.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
        "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.3",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "react-router": "^6.7.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.7.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
        "react-star-rate": "^0.2.0",
        "react-switch": "^7.0.0",
        "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
        "react-use-cart": "^1.13.0",
        "sass": "^1.57.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}

Netlify Log:

3:28:07 PM: build-image version: 68a2c262fa3c95a08a1716b8dde8fba0e332ec73 (focal)
3:28:07 PM: buildbot version: 68a2c262fa3c95a08a1716b8dde8fba0e332ec73
3:28:07 PM: Building without cache
3:28:07 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
3:28:07 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
3:28:07 PM: git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/OsmanAbdullayev/ecommerce-food-final-project
3:28:07 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
3:28:08 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
3:28:10 PM: Starting to install dependencies
3:28:10 PM: Python version set to 3.8
3:28:10 PM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
3:28:11 PM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
3:28:11 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
3:28:11 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
3:28:11 PM: Installing Go version 1.19.5 (requested 1.19.5)
3:28:15 PM: go version go1.19.5 linux/amd64
3:28:16 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
3:28:17 PM: v16.20.0 is already installed.
3:28:17 PM: Now using node v16.20.0 (npm v8.19.4)
3:28:17 PM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
3:28:17 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
3:28:17 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
3:28:17 PM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
3:28:17 PM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
3:28:17 PM: No npm workspaces detected
3:28:17 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
3:28:17 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
3:28:18 PM: Installing npm packages using npm version 8.19.4
3:28:23 PM: npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
3:28:23 PM: npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
3:28:23 PM: npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
3:28:26 PM: npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
3:28:36 PM: added 1606 packages, and audited 1607 packages in 18s
3:28:36 PM: 235 packages are looking for funding
3:28:36 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
3:28:36 PM: 7 high severity vulnerabilities
3:28:36 PM: To address issues that do not require attention, run:
3:28:36 PM:   npm audit fix
3:28:36 PM: To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
3:28:36 PM:   npm audit fix --force
3:28:36 PM: Run `npm audit` for details.
3:28:36 PM: npm packages installed
3:28:36 PM: Install dependencies script success
3:28:36 PM: Starting build script
3:28:37 PM: Detected 1 framework(s)
3:28:37 PM: "create-react-app" at version "5.0.1"
3:28:37 PM: Section completed: initializing
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
3:28:38 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM: ❯ Version
3:28:38 PM:   @netlify/build 29.9.2
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM: ❯ Flags
3:28:38 PM:   baseRelDir: true
3:28:38 PM:   buildId: 64451644de489d1e00101fc8
3:28:38 PM:   deployId: 64451644de489d1e00101fca
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM: ❯ Current directory
3:28:38 PM:   /opt/build/repo
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM: ❯ Config file
3:28:38 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM: ❯ Context
3:28:38 PM:   production
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
3:28:38 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:28:38 PM: ​
3:28:38 PM: $ npm run build
3:28:39 PM: > ecommerce-food-final-project@0.1.0 build
3:28:39 PM: > react-scripts build
3:28:40 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
3:29:30 PM: Compiled with warnings.
3:29:30 PM: 
3:29:30 PM: Warning
3:29:30 PM: (1:584) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
3:29:30 PM: Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
3:29:30 PM: To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
3:29:30 PM: File sizes after gzip:
3:29:30 PM:   490.67 kB  build/static/js/main.cb412f7c.js
3:29:30 PM:   32.59 kB   build/static/css/main.a99261ea.css
3:29:30 PM:   1.8 kB     build/static/js/787.9a0f268f.chunk.js
3:29:30 PM: Starting post processing
3:29:30 PM: The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
3:29:30 PM: You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
3:29:30 PM: The build folder is ready to be deployed.
3:29:30 PM: Post processing - HTML
3:29:30 PM: You may serve it with a static server:
3:29:30 PM:   npm install -g serve
3:29:30 PM:   serve -s build
3:29:30 PM: Find out more about deployment here:
3:29:30 PM: Post processing - header rules
3:29:30 PM:   https://cra.link/deployment
3:29:30 PM: ​
3:29:30 PM: (build.command completed in 51.5s)
3:29:31 PM: Post processing - redirect rules
3:29:30 PM: ​
3:29:30 PM:   2. Deploy site                                                
3:29:30 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:29:31 PM: Post processing done
3:29:30 PM: ​
3:29:30 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'build'
3:29:31 PM: Section completed: postprocessing
3:29:30 PM: Calculating files to upload
3:29:30 PM: 0 new files to upload
3:29:30 PM: 0 new functions to upload
3:29:30 PM: Section completed: deploying
3:29:30 PM: Site deploy was successfully initiated
3:29:30 PM: ​
3:29:30 PM: (Deploy site completed in 127ms)
3:29:30 PM: ​
3:29:30 PM:   Netlify Build Complete                                        
3:29:30 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:29:30 PM: ​
3:29:30 PM: (Netlify Build completed in 51.7s)
3:29:31 PM: Site is live ✨
3:29:31 PM: Caching artifacts
3:29:31 PM: Started saving node modules
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving node modules
3:29:31 PM: Started saving build plugins
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving build plugins
3:29:31 PM: Started saving corepack cache
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving corepack cache
3:29:31 PM: Started saving pip cache
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving pip cache
3:29:31 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
3:29:31 PM: Started saving go dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
3:29:31 PM: Build script success
3:29:31 PM: Section completed: building
3:29:33 PM: Uploading Cache of size 180.5MB
3:29:34 PM: Section completed: cleanup
3:29:34 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m27.279s
```

I checked the whole project for "start" values and couldn't find any. Also, I googled it and couldn't find any solutions, reinstalled react, react-bootstrap. I added a environmental variable "CI=false" in deploy settings, the project was deployed but the warning still persists.

Answer (score 5):

In .css,I fixed it by changing the justify-content:start to justify-content:flex-start and it worked for me and webpack compiled successfully without warning

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by changing

```css
align-items: start
```

to

```css
align-items: flex-start
```

in  "OrderDetails.module.scss"